GeoNetwork duplicates number of EPSG code/CRS information each time the harvester is running
I am using GeoNetwork 4.4.5. I have created an OGC Web Service harvester that ingests Vector data from a GeoServer WMS (WMS 1.3.0).
So far I only created one dataset in order to test the GeoNetwork and GeoServer interaction. However, this one dataset is duplicating the CRS information each time I am running the harvester.
In GeoServer the vector dataset is stored in EPSG: 25833. Once I start the harvester, the data shows EPSG: 25833 and CRS: 84

Now I am re-running the harvester, e.g. because I added some data on GeoServer side: The dataset that has been harvested before is the same and is not being duplicated. The information about the EPSG code and CRS is being duplicated however:

I don't think this is supposed to be "normal" behavior. Are there any settings that might lead to a multiple CRS/EPSG code entry?
Just let me know in case you need any additional information about the GeoServer or GeoNetwork settings.

Addendum:
This problem seems connected with the WMS version using in the harvester. When using WMS 1.1.1, only the EPSG code (25833) is transmitted, once you run the harvester. After running the harvester another time, no further EPSG codes or CRS information is being added.
However, when using WMS 1.3.0 the EPSG code (25833) AND the CRS information (WGS84) is being transmitted; and duplicated each time when you re-run the harvester.

I have heard that GeoNetwork 4.2 does not have that issue. Could you make also a test with GN 4.2?

Probably worth logging on the GeoNetwork Issue tracker: https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/issues

Thanks for the hint @user30184! Unfortunately we were told to use the most current version of GN, so this is not an option at that moment. Maybe, if the problem persists, at a later point of time.

Thanks for the link @HeikkiVesanto! I wasn't aware of the issue tracker and checked it out. However, I couldn't find the issue that I have. Will keep looking or open a new issue there!
